# Subrows into a row in GridView using WPF & C#

Tags: wpf, gridview, templates, rows

In my gridview I need to aggregate subrows into each row, something like in p2p emule/amule application where you can do double click to each file you are downloading and then under it you can see the parts of the file from where you are downloading.

Is it possible in WPF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things:

Add some container (ie: another Grid or a StackPanel) to the Grid row.  This would let you add multiple objects to the grid row.  On your "double click" event, you could change the visibility to show those objects.

Use a TreeView with a HierarchicalDataTemplate, and treat this as hierarchical data.  This is most likely the more "correct" approach.  The [Displaying Hierarchical Data sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771440.aspx) walks through the process of this.